# how to force sevlet to send a String as attachment to browser?

Tags: java, servlets, content-disposition

I want to send a String to user
Actually I don't have any file for it. It is only a standard java string and I want user to download it rather than see it on browser.

Most of the example on internet are based on a static file which is not useful for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

austin,i think you need set the response header,following is the code:

```
getResponse().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=filename");
getResponse().setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
getResponse().setHeader("Cache-Control" , "no-cache");
getResponse().setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

where the getResponse() gets the httpServletResponse.

Comment: Then what about sending characters? can I use getWritter().print("blah") ?

Comment: yeah,getResponse().getWriter().print("something") .